# Power Supply Prematurely Off

Tags: power-supply

I have a Gateway HP-AN235D43 power supply that is 12 V and supposed to output up to 19.6 A. I want to use it to power two 55 W car headlight bulbs, adding up to about 10 A. However, it works only with one bulb, drawing about 4.6 A. When I put two bulbs in parallel, the PSU would not turn on, measuring 0 V on its output.

Is this another symptom of the failing capacitors? I would like to have some idea before opening it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Measure the cold resistance of the bulbs. You’ll find that it is much lower than the wattage would imply. Incandescent filaments have a much lower cold resistance that increases as they warm up. This means that your 4.6 amp bulb will probably draw well over 10 amps at startup. Your power supply can probably supply additional surge amperage at startup but not enough for two bulbs and it’s going into overcurrent shutdown.

Your power supply is probably just fine.

Comment: Thanks! That must be it. The cold resistance is too small to measure on my cheap analog multimeter. What should I do? Add an inductor in series?

Comment: Tying an inductor worked.

Comment: If my answer helped, I’d appreciate you “accepting” it by clicking the check mark. Thanks.